# permutation test compute observed t-score

Tags: r

I would like to write a function to perform permutation test, but struggling with how to compute the observed t-score and the permuted scores, and also plot the empirical distribution

Error in var(y) : Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct. Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.

```
permutation.test <- function

(
    gene,         # gene 
    pheno,        # (binary) phenotype, must be a factor
    nperm,        # number of permutation iterations
    alternative=c("two.sided","less","greater"),
    smooth=0,     # smoothing factor to avoid pval=0
    seed=NULL,    # random seed (for reproducible results)
    do.plot=FALSE # plot the empirical distribution of permuted t-scores
)
{
    ## compute the _observed_ t-score
    obs <- t.test(gene~pheno,var.equal=TRUE)["statistic"]

    ## compute the _permuted_ scores
    perm  <- replicate(1000, t.test(gene, pheno))["statistic"]
    
    ## compute the empirical p-value
    pval <- mean(abs(perm) > abs(obs))/1000
      
    
    if ( do.plot ) {
      hist(perm)
      abline(v=obs, lwd=2, col="purple")
      mean(abs(perm) > abs(obs))
    }
    return(pval)
}

time1 <- system.time(
  p2 <- permutation.test(gene=gene,pheno=as.factor(pheno),nperm=1000,seed=123,do.plot=TRUE)
)
print(time1)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see what `gene` and `pheno` look like. Normally in a permutation test, the outcome or the treatment is randomly shuffled and then a test statistic is computed and compared to the observed. I do not see in your code any random shuffling of `gene` or `pheno`.

Comment: Assuming that 'geno' is a continuous variable (which seems unlikely given the usual notion of a gene as a discrete sort of entity) one would need to insert a `sample` call to rearrange either the 'geno' or the 'pheno' variables. I'm kind of wondering if this is homework?